# Determining parameters of Poisson distributions from their difference

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ be two independent random variables with Poisson distributions $Po(\lambda), Po(\mu)$ respectively. We don't know the values of $\mu$ and $\lambda$, but we know that $P(X>Y) = a, P(X=Y) = b$, where $a, b$ are known constants. Is there some good way how to determine $\mu$ and $\lambda$ from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as $a+b\lt 1$ and $b$ is not too small, it looks fairly simple to set up an optimistion problem with $\displaystyle a = \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!} e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^j}{j!} $  $\displaystyle , b = \sum_{i=0}^k e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!} e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^i}{i!} $ for some suitably large $k$, and then use your favorite optimiation software.

Doing so with Excel's solver gave the following illustrative approximate results, which in particular show that a smaller $b$ tends to lead to larger $\lambda$ and $\mu$ (and the need for a larger $k$).

```
a       b        lambda  mu
0.3     0.6999   0.3567  0.0001
0.3     0.6      0.4171  0.1590
0.3     0.5      0.5058  0.3632
0.3     0.4      0.6512  0.6512
0.3     0.3      0.9392  1.1333
0.3     0.2      1.7549  2.2801
0.3     0.1      6.2794  7.7330
0.3     0.05    24.4076 27.6896
0.5999  0.4      0.9163  0.0002
0.5     0.4      0.8753  0.2445
0.4     0.4      0.7884  0.4666
0.3     0.4      0.6512  0.6512
0.2     0.4      0.4666  0.7884
0.1     0.4      0.2445  0.8753
0.0001  0.4      0.0002  0.9163
```

Comment: Btw. how can you see that $\lambda, \mu$ are uniquely determined by those conditions?

Comment: I think it is fairly obvious that if $a=\frac{1-b}{2}$ then $\lambda = \mu$ and that they reduce together as $b$ increases.  But for fixed $b$, $\lambda$ increases with $a$ and $\mu$ falls as $a$ increases.